# Comparing substrings in Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I want to Query the two table depending on the condition and want to generate the Tag as you can see in the image yes/maybe
[image: for generating the following result the query is]

For displaying the above result i am using `if(places.name CONTAINS poi.name 'Yes','Maybe')` but the problem is : in the image on line no.  4 `poi_name` contain the value `surana.agen` and its respective column `places_type` have the value `[W1]Surana.Agency` and hence i want the `Tag` as **Yes** instead of **Maybe**.
 `poi_name` column can have the any special character like here dot(.) i want to split the columns values by whichever the special character present and in this case i want to search for the `surana` or `agen` present in the `places_name`.

Any help appreciable
Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far ? show some of your actual work!

Comment: above image is nothing but result of my query on poi and places table

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, I'd suggest thinking about this problem as follows:

- Step 1: Split poi_name into the substrings that you want to match.
- Step 2: Check whether any of those substrings are contained in places_name.

For Step 1, it's hard to pull apart an arbitrary number of substrings in SQL. However, if you have some limit in mind (e.g., at most 3 substrings), you could pull them out using REGEXP_EXTRACT. For example:

```
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(poi_name, r'([^.]*)') AS first,
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(poi_name, r'[^.]*\.([^.]*)') AS second,
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(poi_name, r'[^.]*\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)') AS third,
```

Fortunately, Step 2 is easy. Once you've extracted those strings, use CONTAINS to test whether they're in places_name.

I'm not sure how much control you have over your input, but you might consider splitting poi_name into separate fields or into a repeated field in advance, since that would avoid the need to run REGEXP_EXTRACT on every query.

Answer (score 0):

My Query for the above image ios

```
SELECT a.id as ID, 
a.lattitude as poi_lat,
b.latitude as places_lat,
a.longitude as poi_long,
b.longitude as places_long,
a.name as poi_name,
a.comment as poi_comment,
b.name as places_name,
b.type as places_type,
if(b.name CONTAINS a.name 
AND b.lat_approximate = a.lat_approximate 
AND b.long_approximate = a.long_approximate, 
'Yes', 
if(b.lat_approximate = a.lat_approximate 
AND b.long_approximate = a.long_approximate, 'Maybe','No') 
) as Tag
FROM [grayrout_graycover.poientry_test] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [grayrout_graycover.placesdetails] b
ON a.lat_approximate = b.lat_approximate AND a.long_approximate = b.long_approximate 
WHERE b.type='P&G'
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected result for the question above by changing the condition in the select clause as `if(UPPER(b.name) CONTAINS UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(a.name, r'\.\w*', ''))OR UPPER(b.name) CONTAINS UPPER(a.name) AND b.lat_approximate = a.lat_approximate AND b.long_approximate = a.long_approximate AND b.type='P&G', 'Yes', if(b.lat_approximate = a.lat_approximate AND b.long_approximate = a.long_approximate AND b.type='P&G', 'May be','Not') ) as Tag`
but it gives annoying result as bellow [image]

line no 246 which is Ok but line no 241 giving wrong result the Tag must be Yes.
after getting this result I want to optimize it for line no 242 and 243.

Comment: Consider breaking out each of those conditions in your IF statement into a separate column in the result. That way you can get more info about why the expression evaluated as observed. Also consider parenthesizing the AND and OR clause to make sure you're getting the result you expect.

Comment: I check down the conditions very well its working fine some places i thing their is problem with the data

Comment: Is their any natural language support in BigQuery I mean, can compare the two strings and get the some sort of percent match so that we can predict How much two string are identical for eg. in my image above line no 242,243 Medical compare with Medicals which will give percent match let say 99% check the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Nope, BigQuery does not yet support natural language or "fuzzy" string matching. However, the problem as you've posed it should be solvable in BigQuery. I don't have enough info to debug based on your post, but I suspect you could find a solution by testing smaller expressions.